# Change the name of CSS import dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the name of CSS import dynamically using jquery.
from

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Theme.css">

to

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueTheme.css">

HTML

```
<div class="theme-pallete">
   <button class="blue active" data-theme="Theme">Blue</button>
   <button class="golden" data-theme="goldenTheme">Golden</button>
   <button class="purple" data-theme="purpleTheme">Purple</button>
   <button class="pink" data-theme="pinkTheme">Pink</button>
   <button class="red" data-theme="redTheme">Theme</button>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.theme-pallete button').on('click', function () {
    var sheetName = $(this).attr('data-theme');
    $('link[href$="Theme.css"]').attr('href', '/css/' + sheetName + '.css');
});
```

It works fine on local system but problem arise when Base Url comes into the picture

Please note I don't want to hard code the base URL because of it changes based on hosting environment like

> app.project.com/baseurl/css/Theme.css
>   app.project.com/UAT/css/Theme.css
>  
>   app.project.com/design/css/Theme.css

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a [function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)(where 2nd argument would be old value) and replace the method.

```
$('.theme-pallete button').on('click', function () {
    var sheetName = 'blueTheme';
    $('link[href$="Theme.css"]').attr('href', (i, value) => value.replace(/Theme\.css$/, sheetName + '.css');
});
```

Comment: I liked the approach. Works perfectly fine for the first time, but the value for variable sheetName keeps on changing dynamically on click of buttons. I have updated the code. Please revise your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the themename with the new then name

```
function changeCssURL(themename){
 $("button").click(function(){
   $('link[href$="Theme.css"]').attr("href", "app.project.com/UAT/css/"+themename+".css");
  });
}
```

Comment: Any solution where don't have to hard code baseurl `app.project.com/UAT/` because it won't work on **app.project.com/design/css/Theme.css**

Comment: can you use a session variable ? if yes then you do something lke this 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("public/css/app-".(\Session::has('theme') ? \Session::get('theme') : 'green').".css") }}" />